# Clone pivot table with Apache POI 3.9?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

Does anyone have any idea how to use Apache POI to read a pivot table from an existing excel file and then add it to a new file?

I already tried to clone an existing sheet, but unfortunately only the values were copied, hence it cannot be done this way...

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [limitations](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) on the POI site, you can't create a new pivot table.

That being said, what I'd recommend (and the system that I work on does) is to use a template pivot table.  Open that pivot table, clear out all rows except for the first row (row #0, as they are 0-based), then write your data into the appropriate columns and rows.  Finally write out the spreadsheet as a new file and there you go, you've got a clone of your pivot table.

Comment: what do you mean by "clear out all rows except for the first row"?

Comment: Try something like this:
`Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
  Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
  if (row != null) {
    sheet.removeRow(row);
  }
}`